# How to use a fully custom Ui for swagger UI when it is used in the front end (React Js)?

Tags: swagger, customization, swagger-ui

I am unable to customize the swagger Ui with my own layout. I only need to get the functionality of swagger Ui. Is there a possible way to do this?